# Why does my Kafka Consumer consume messages quickly on first run, but slows down considerably in future runs?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am a student researching and playing around with Kafka. After following the examples on the Apache documentation, I'm playing around with the examples portion in the trunk of their current Github repo.

As of right now, the example implements an 'older' version of their `Consumer` and does not employ the new `KafkaConsumer`. Following the documentation, I have written my own version of the `KafkaConsumer` thinking that it would be faster.

This is a vague question, but on runthrough I produce 5000 simple messages such as "Message_CurrentMessageNumber" to a topic "test" and then use my consumer to fetch these messages and print them to `stdout`. When I run the example code replacing the provided consumer with the newer `KafkaConsumer` (v 0.8.2 and up) it works pretty quickly and comparably to the example in its first runthrough, but slows down considerably anytime after that.

I notice that my `Kafka Server` outputs

> Rebalancing group group1 generation 3 (kafka.coordinator.ConsumerCoordinator)

or similar messages often which leads me to believe that Kafka has to do some sort of load balancing that slows stuff down but I was wondering if anyone else had insight as to what I am doing wrong.

```
public class AlternateConsumer extends Thread {

    private final KafkaConsumer<Integer, String> consumer;
    private final String topic;
    private final Boolean isAsync = false;

     public AlternateConsumer(String topic) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.put("group.id", "newestGroup");
        properties.put("partition.assignment.strategy", "roundrobin");
        properties.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        properties.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        properties.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        properties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer");
        properties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<Integer, String>(properties);
        consumer.subscribe(topic);
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record : records) {
                System.out.println("We received message: " + record.value() + " from topic: " + record.topic());
            }
        }

        // ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> records = consumer.poll(0);
        // for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record : records) {
        //  System.out.println("We received message: " + record.value() + " from topic: " + record.topic());
        // }
        // consumer.close();
    }
}
```

To start:

```
package kafka.examples;

public class KafkaConsumerProducerDemo implements KafkaProperties
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final boolean isAsync = args.length > 0 ? !args[0].trim().toLowerCase().equals("sync") : true;

    Producer producerThread = new Producer("test", isAsync);
    producerThread.start();

    AlternateConsumer consumerThread = new AlternateConsumer("test");
    consumerThread.start();
  } 
}
```

The producer is the default producer located here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/Producer.java

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example you followed ? Are you using some kind of consumer group ? How are you consuming the messages, which library ?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/examples - I followed the example in this link and studied the code in the directories to understand what was going on. As for how I rewrote the code, if you look at the Consumers.java file, it is not using the updated Kafka Consumer api located here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer under KafkaConsumer.

I rewrote the Consumer.java class to use the newer KafkaConsumer structure which supposedly has higher throughput, and that's about it. I think the problem is caused by rebalancing.

Comment: Yes possible, but you shouldn't see this message often. Can you share what configuration you are using spcifically; session.timeout.ms and heartbeat.frequency. Did you try running your test jacking these values up ? How often do you see this message in your log ? Also if you can add some more details around your test: 1) are you comparing performance by restarting your consumers? 2) do you see rebalance only in the subsequent run and not in the 1st run?

Comment: Currently I don't have anything for the heartbeat setting so I'm guessing it defaults and I have 30,000 for my session.timeout.ms. 

For details about my test:
1) Yeah, which I think may be problematic, I'm rerunning the producer and consumer each time and it seems like the consumers are of the same group.id's which means every successive time Kafka thinks there are more and more consumers (my guess)
2) Yes, but only if I switch up my consumers to a new group ID. I actually think the issue is because all my consumers same group ID and im not threading them do you have insight on that?

Comment: Ideally for the sort test runs like this you should see the partition assignment once at the beginning, is that the case ? 
Consumer belonging to same group should not be the issue, but yes, if your comparable test on the older consumer is using the threaded implementation you should do the same for this and that is how you will anyway implement your consumer. 
Also can you confirm that you are doing cleanup `close()` on the consumer at the end of each run.

If possible, can you post your consumer and the runnable test that will help understand better.

Comment: thanks for all the help so far MSD, i really appreciate it. i will post my tests in just a bit but i'm still a little confused on a few details: my current producer is producing to some topic with one hundred randomly generated messages but only to a single partition. does that fact that i am not partitioning my data cause issues when i introduce more consumers? i think i read on the kafka documentation that a single consumer consumes the entirety of a partition, so maybe adding more consumers doesn't help me at all in terms of speed? i am also not using close()..where is that located?

Comment: How are you creating your topic ? You will need to create the topic with multiple partition first. Isn't topic/partition same when you are comparing old and new consumers. How are you storing data to a single partition ? If you are using the key then default partitioner should take care of spreading your data across available partitions. `close` is available under KafkaConsumer.

Comment: Originally I created my topic using the command bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test which of course does not have multiple partitions. Is it okay for me to create my topics on command line and then reference them in my code? Also, currently I am having my consumer run indefinitely else it will crash if I try to close it even if I allow it to wait indefinitely for messages. Lastly, what is the best way for me to show you some of my code? Should I link you to my github repo? Thanks for all the help again!

Comment: Yes you can use topic/partition like you mentioned. Either you can post your relevant code here or github link is also ok.

Answer (score 1):

This should not be the case. If the setup is similar between your two consumers you should expect better result with new consumer unless there is issue in the client/consumer implementation, which seems to be the case here.

Can you share your benchmark results and the frequency of reported rebalancing and/or any pattern (i.e. sluggish once at startup, after fixed message consumption, after the queue is drained, etc) you are observing. Also if you can share some details about your consumer implementation.

Comment: I have edited my question so you can see some of my implementations. I'm going to recheck and restart this soon with a topic with multiple partitions, but please let me know if you see anything wrong in the meantime!

Comment: Since this is right off the doc, don't expect an issue here except that it is single threaded like you mentioned. Let us know how your test goes. Please expect to see some re-balances at the beginning while you subscribe you consumers. If you dont want this you may consider using ` KafkaConsumber.subscribe(TopicPartition... partitions)`, of-course with some trade-offs.

Comment: It looks like adding a topic with multiple partitions and running my tests again were not helpful, in the sense that the same issues persisted with the first test returning my messages quickly (albeit in a scrambled manner now due to having multiple partitions) and further tests produced rebalancing. @MSD I believe my issue is from this line I found in documentation 'when a new process is started with the same Consumer Group name, Kafka will add that processes' threads to the set of threads available to consume the Topic and trigger a 're-balance'

Comment: Do you have any advice for using a multiple threaded high level consumer? It looks like that is the source of my issue - that or I have failed to understand fundamentally how consumers in a single consumer group interact with a multiple partitioned topic.

Comment: All i am trying to say is, if you are seeing the rebalance once at startup when you are creating/subscribing the consumer its normal and that is expected. Given the fact that once you setup your consumer it will consume messages for a relatively extended period and hence it should not matter much when you measure the throughput of the overall run. This is slightly different compared to old consumer where you have the ability to generate multiple streams within a single command `ConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(Map<String,Integer> topicPartitionMap)`